# Component-Entity Systems Code Generation

Tags: entity-system, levels, architecture, entity-component, configuration

I'm really enjoying component entity approach (I'm currently using ASH haxe, but particular language/framework doesn't really matter).

However the problem is - there're way too many elementary classes that need frequent update.

So I'd like to have something like yml config file for components and nodes, and actual classes to be generated from it. Is there any already existing solution that utilizes such codegen, or maybe some generic codegen solution that should be easy to configure for such task?

Comment: Switch to C# and Visual Studio. Then you will be able to simply use the T4 templates: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_Template_Transformation_Toolkit

Comment: Any chance you could make that an answer @Den?

Comment: @Shroeder OK, done.

Comment: @user54415 what are "nodes" by the way?

Comment: This appears to be fundamentally a question about "how to generate code from templates," which is not game-development specific. If that isn't the case, please edit your question to provide more details about the specifics the system you would like to build.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I disagree as CES is a de-facto game-specific architecture.  Configuring it is an interesting subject.

Comment: Just because something is *about* games doesn't make it on-topic here; it's whether or not game developers would give a better answer. Game developers are not any more likely than regular programmers to provide answers about *code generation techniques*, which are universal. The fact that this is for a component system is, as currently written, incidental.

Answer (score 1):

I see two options:

1) Run-time code configuration.
Traditional use case would be typical scene (level) data files.
Typically a custom implementation is used (could be using a well-known transport such as XML and JSON).

Disadvantages: potentially more work to implement, limited to code configuration rather than generation (scripting aside).

Advantages: run-time configuration potential (e.g. user level editing), high format flexibility.

2) Compile/build time code generation.
Typically third-party solutions are used:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_code_generation_tools

Disadvantages: typically limited to compile/build time, very coder-oriented.

Advantages: simpler to get something working, closer to code.

I only have some minor experience using T4 in Visual Studio and it seems that it works.
Visual Studio is considered one of the best IDEs and there are some good T4 extensions for it as well.

This topic is very close to Domain Specific Languages design and implementation, so it might be worth exploring as well.